# Cassandra - Strange behaviour with one node

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a cluster with 3 nodes in my developer environment, with a keyspace and a replication factor = 2, originally I had only one node in this cluster but then I added 2 more nodes, one by one. Cassandra version is 3.7.

All these nodes are "clones" so I just modified the cassandra.yaml with the corresponding IP for every node.

I've done a repair and cleanup on every node, and in my application, I have a consistency level ONE.

This is the nodetool status output:

```
Datacenter: dc1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.132.0.4  50.54 GiB  256          70.2%             50dc5baf-b8b3-4e19-8173-cf828afd36af  rack1
UN  10.132.0.3  50.31 GiB  256          65.3%             2a45b7a5-41ce-4533-ba63-60fd3c5cc530  rack1
UN  10.132.0.9  33.88 GiB  256          64.5%             e601fb16-6608-4e72-a820-dd4661977946  rack1
```

In the Cassandra.yaml I have only 10.132.0.3 as the seed node.

So at this point, everything works fine and as expected, if I turn down one node everything keeps running "fine" unless if this node is 10.132.0.9, if I turn down this "bad" node everything crashes with the following error:

> org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM

When I stop the bad node, the good ones show this error in his system.log files (I only copy the error not the entire StackTrace):

> ERROR [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2018-02-27 10:59:16,449 QueryMessage.java:128 - Unexpected error during query
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM

I don't understand what's wrong with this node and I don't find a solution...

---

**Edit**

My connection code:

```
cluster_builder = Cluster.builder()
                .addContactPoints(serverIP.getCassandraList(sysvar))
                .withAuthProvider(new PlainTextAuthProvider(serverIP.getCassandraUser(sysvar), serverIP.getCassandraPwd(sysvar))).withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions)
                .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ONE));

        cluster     = cluster_builder.build();
        session     = cluster.connect(keyspace);
```

My query:

```
statement   = QueryBuilder.insertInto(keyspace, "measurement_minute").values(this.normal_names, (List<Object>) values);
```

And the execution:

```
ResultSetFuture future = session.executeAsync(statement.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ONE));
```

I want to mention that I restarted, repaired and cleaned up all the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting `QUORUM` with a replication factor of 2. This won't really work well as you are really requesting `ALL`. For a quorum, a majority of your nodes need to respond to your query.

You can calculate the node count for a quorum with (RF/2)+1 (using integer arithmetic), so RF=2 gives (2/2)+1=2 - you need both of your replicas and can't have one down. The reason for some queries to work is that those don't use 10.132.0.9.

You can go with a replication factor of RF=3 or use CL.ONE for example.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm not understanding what u mean with requesting, but in my client i've set consistencylevel ONE, and the problem only apears when I shut down the 10.132.0.9 node.

Comment: Somehow the client is still using quorum as the consistency level, otherwise you wouldn't get those errors. Can you give an example of your client?

Comment: Edited the question, but if the client is still using QUORUM shouldn't it crash when I turn down any node, not only the 10.132.0.9 node.

Comment: it will only crash if the query cant be fulfilled - if your query does not hit data on 10.132.0.9 they will work anyway.